# parallelize threads for speed

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am trying to recover a lost zip file password and i made this script to try crack it

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import string


characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '$#&*@'


zip_file = "jl_update_file (1)"

def try_password(password):

    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
            zf.extractall(pwd=password.encode())
        print(f"\nPassword cracked: {password}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\rTrying password: {password}", end='')
        return False

def crack_zip():
    for length in range(6, 13):  # Range from 4 to 12 inclusive
        for combination in itertools.product(characters, repeat=length):
            password = ''.join(combination)
            if try_password(password):
                return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    crack_zip()
```

Everytime i try to use threads to try make it faster, each thread makes the same attempts making it redunant and not having any affect. I would like to know how to use parrellization to be able to increase speed.

I have tried this

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import string
import concurrent.futures

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '$#&*@'

zip_file = "jl_update_file (1)"
tried_passwords = set()

def try_password(password):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
            zf.extractall(pwd=password.encode())
        print(f"\nPassword cracked: {password}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\rTrying password: {password}", end='')
        return False

def crack_zip(length):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for combination in itertools.product(characters, repeat=length):
            password = ''.join(combination)
            if password not in tried_passwords:
                tried_passwords.add(password)
                executor.submit(try_password, password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for length in range(6, 13):  # Range from 4 to 12 inclusive
        crack_zip(length)
```

and

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import string
import concurrent.futures

characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '$#&*@'

zip_file = "jl_update_file (1)"
tried_passwords = set()

def try_password(password):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zf:
            zf.extractall(pwd=password.encode())
        print(f"\nPassword cracked: {password}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"\rTrying password: {password}", end='')
        return False

def crack_zip(length):
    global tried_passwords  # Declare tried_passwords as global
    max_tries = 10
    tries = 0
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for combination in itertools.product(characters, repeat=length):
            password = ''.join(combination)
            if password not in tried_passwords:
                tried_passwords.add(password)
                tries += 1
                executor.submit(try_password, password)
                if tries >= max_tries:
                    tried_passwords = set(sorted(tried_passwords)[-max_tries:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for length in range(4, 13):  # Range from 4 to 12 inclusive
        crack_zip(length)
```

I am unable to speed up process using threads becuase either it slows down or has no effect. can anyone help me so i can learn how to use parrell processing to make things go faster?

Comment: Threads in python cannot speed up CPU-bound code due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) meaning that only 1 thread executes at any one time. Look into `multiprocessing`

Comment: You have 67 characters to choose from. 67^12 is 8182718904632857144561, just saying... And `set(sorted(tried_passwords)[-max_tries:])` definitely doesn't help.

Comment: Or, in this case `ProcessPoolExecutor` but you will still need to figure out how to stop them doing duplicate work.

Comment: I must be missing something, but doesn't the call to `itertools.product` return unique passwords and if so why would each thread be making the same attempt?. You will also be submitting tasks faster than they can complete, so why is it that you do not exhaust memory fairly quickly?